# af:poll timeout is not working as expected

Tags: oracle, tomcat7, oracle-adf

I'm using `af:poll` in a page.

```
    <af:poll binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_pages_xyzView.p2}"
             id="p2"
             interval="#{sessionScope.manage_Template.dataRefreshRate}"
             pollListener="#{backingBeanScope.backing_pages_xzy.pollTablexyzView}"
             partialTriggers="resId1" timeout="36000000"/>
```

I have set a large value for `timeout` parameter as I don't want this page to timeout after the default 10 mins period. 
However, page still times out after 10 mins time. Here's a screenshot.[image]

Why is this happening? If I set a duration less than 10 mins as the `timeout`, it works.
Here is the documentation I referred http://docs.oracle.com/html/E12419_09/tagdoc/af_poll.html

Note: This Oracle web app is configured to run in tomcat 7.0.16 (ADF version: 11.1.1.7)

UPDATE: When I remove the partialTriggers="resId1" it works. Why?

Comment: It may be because your application session timeout is set to 10 mins in web.xml

Comment: @amishra Tried it. Not the case apparently.

Comment: @amishra  When I remove the partialTriggers="resId1" it works

Comment: Just wondering why do you have partialTrigger on resId, do you want to trigger the poll when there is a change in resId1?

Comment: @amishra I can live without that of course. Having said that, why does it misbehave when the partialTrigger is used. Another thing I noticed is that poll is defined after the table is defined (in the jspx file) should the order matter?

Comment: If I am understanding it right then you want to refresh resId1 after certain interval so that the page remains active. In that case resId1 should have partialTrigger="p2". If you are setting partialTriggers="resId1" on p2, it means that poll value will be updated whenever there is a change in resId. check this out for ref: https://mjabr.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/refresh-part-of-the-page-periodically-using-poll-component/

Comment: @amishra thanks for the helpful input